# Is a light leak around front door considered normal?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

My front door has light leaking around the weatherstripping. It was really bad, then apartment mgmt sent a maintenance tech out who replaced some of the weatherstripping, now it’s half as bad.

I just need a sanity check - is this light leaking around my front door (to exterior) normal? Surely there should be 0 light at all, right?

It’s really hot here outside and also bugs come in, I think through the gaps…

Before the “fix”
[image: Before the fix]

After the “fix”
[image: After the fix]

Comment: Is that direct light passing by the seal, or illumination from light passing _through_ the seal?

Comment: Is this a door to the outside or to a lit corridor?

Comment: Can you measure the gap between the door and the frame at the widest point?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, no. Not OK.

Talk to the manager, show the pics, tell them it needs to be fixed.